# Desktop Facebook Logout

Tags: facebook, desktop, logout

I have a desktop application that uses facebook authentication in offline mode.  There is no session key as the app returns me an access token.

It stores the access token and allows the user to post to facebook at other desktop app locations around an event.

The problem I'm having is that after a user goes through the oauth, I can't clear the session data for the next user.

I've tried deleting all the cookies, but that causes a facebook script error when the next user tries to authenticate...

I'm simply looking for a way to remove the session cache from the machine and not cause javascript errors...

Answer (score 0):

This is the closest I've found to anyone figuring this out.  It doesn't work for me, though:
http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=84232

My problem is that I can't log the user out if they haven't authorized my app and returned an access token yet.